# Blockchain study material for carrier

Tags: blockchain, solidity, ibm-blockchain

I have 8+ years of experience in the IT industry as a Quality Analyst. I have experience in Manual and Automation testing in the Health Care domain.

Now I am bored with this carrier path and want to learn BlockChain and make carrier in that only. I have started taking some courses on the basics of blockchain and currently going through smart contract creation with solidity from Udemy. This course cover solidity and creating some frontend using javascript to interact with Smart contracts.

Can someone please guide me in the right direction? I have basic knowledge of Java and python and good at logical to create programs.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can proceed by following that and as you want to make carrier in blockchain only you may try different Hyperledger projects.Till now, Hyperledger Fabric is the most popular Hyperledger blockchain framework.

[Hyperledger](https://www.hyperledger.org/) is an open source community focused on developing a suite of stable frameworks, tools and libraries for enterprise-grade blockchain deployments.
It serves as a neutral home for various distributed ledger frameworks including Hyperledger Fabric, Sawtooth, Indy, as well as tools like Hyperledger Caliper and libraries like Hyperledger Ursa.

You may check Hyperledger Fabric blockchain framework. There you can write smart contract on Java as you have knowledge on that language. You may also check Hyperledger Indy, where you can use your Python skills.